# How to remove empty space from char variable

Tags: c++, space

I have c-style string variable `char name[25]`. Now, when I input less than 25 symbols, I can't write it to a binary file. My file contains this: `ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌsomething`. How o remove space symbols ?

Comment: Please show the code of how do you write your char array into the file, and how you read the data into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove spaces from c_str:

```
const char *c_str = " some ";
string str = string(c_str);

str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

cout << str << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

In a binary file you will need to keep track of how many bytes to read as the valid data yourself.
Usually this is done by writing two fields to the file:
`sizeofpayload` and then the `actualpayload`
At the time of reading the data the reader program reads the first field and knows how much data to read further for actual payload.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: Thanks :) About time the Android phone gave away to reveal the real hacker? hope so :P